# model:generate gives "Missing required arguments: name, attributes"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, windows-console

I'm on the Windows console and here is a script of my `package.json`:

```
scripts: {
    ...
    "sequelize": "node_modules\\.bin\\sequelize.cmd"
}
```

When I run this command: `npm run-script sequelize model:generate --name Person --attributes name:string,age:integer`, I get this error:

> Missing required arguments: name, attributes

But when I run this command: `node_modules\.bin\sequelize.cmd model:generate --name Person --attributes name:string,age:integer` it works well.

Why do I get this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Running this command

```
npm run sequelize model:generate --name User --attributes name:string
```

will run this(not passing the args):

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize
```

passing arguments through npm is done by adding an extra `--`:

```
npm run sequelize -- model:generate --name User --attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this command

`sequelize migration:create --name migrationName`

this command working 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
npm run -- model:generate --name MyUser --attributes
```

This worked for me.